# Detect <div>'s scroll by pixel number

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Here is a scrollable div and a span;
How can I write a script in order to achieve the following function?

```js
$("span").hide();
$(".box").scroll(function() {
  if (/* <div> scolling is euqal or less than 10px away from bottom: */){
    $("span").show();
  } else {
    $("span").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" style="overflow: auto; height:100px">
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
</div>
<span>Reached bottom</span>
```

Comment: You cab find the remaining pixels first & then reduce the offsetY from it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some of offset api.

For jquery look at: `$(something).offset()`

or

vanila js: `window.pageYOffset` and `scroll` event

Comment: Idk about jQuery , but that vanilla js statenent returns the offset of the entire page.

Comment: You can select required element aka `getElementById("demo")` and look at there attributes like `offsetTop`